# Python cannot import name timegm

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-requests

Import requests is not working any more. I have two same servers Ubuntu 11.10 with python 2.7.2+ , django 1.4.0 and requests 2.0.1. I one server import requests print this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
     from . import utils
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/requests/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
     from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/requests/compat.py", line 89, in <module>
     import cookielib
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 38, in <module>
     from calendar import timegm
 ImportError: cannot import name timegm
```

In the other server it is working. I searched for a solution and the only thing I found was about if there is another calendar.py file somewhere. I searched and there is no other calendar.py

Comment: Do you have a file called `calendar.py` in your code base?

Comment: No, maybe there is some problem with the dependencies?

Comment: I just had a feeling that you have another file called `calendar.py` so the default import would look at your file instead of the default file. Maybe reinstall `requests`?

Comment: I just did it. Still the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could also be a stray calendar.pyc somewhere.

Try this:

```
import calendar
print calendar.__file__
```

This will tell you what module it's loading.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/calendar.pyc
```

Comment: >>> import calendar
>>> print calendar.__file__
calendar/__init__.pyc  

Is it ok?

Comment: Ok I understand. I had a folder calendar in the same place!! thank you